# Is there a built-in function in DolphinDB to compress files into a Zip file?

Tags: zip, compression, dolphindb

We are using DolphinDB in the following scenarios:

1. Backtesting analysis (using the `peach` function for multiple strategies)

- extract basic data from partitioned tables
- perform backtesting
- store the results in the database
- export the results as CSV files to a temporary directory
- compress the files into a Zip archive and store it in the target path, i.e., a remote NAS disk mounted on the Docker container

2. Query the calculation results

Here is my question: is there a built-in function in DolphinDB to compress files into a Zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, a built-in compression function is still under development. Now you can use shell commands to invoke the system’s `zip` command to compress files. Refer to the following script:

```
// compress the files in a directory into a Zip archive
def zipDirFiles(srcDir, destFile, isMoveSrcFile=false) {
        if(!exists(srcDir)) {
                throw 'Source directory does not exist：' + srcDir;
        }

        if (isMoveSrcFile) {
                zipParams = "-rm1";
        } else {
                zipParams = "-r1";
        }
        
        cdCmd = 'cd "' + srcDir + '"';  // Quotation marks "" are used to handle spaces in the path.
        zipCmd = 'zip ' + zipParams + ' "' + destFile + '" *';  // Quotation marks "" are used to handle spaces in the path.
        retCode = shell(cdCmd + ' && ' + zipCmd);
        if(retCode != 0) {
                throw "Failed to compress folder，code：" + retCode;
        }
}
// test
srcDir, destFile, isMoveSrcFile = "/qirp/temp/", "/qirp/123.zip", true;
zipDirFiles(srcDir, destFile, isMoveSrcFile);
```